# c# chart epplus axis reverse order

Tags: charts, reverse, epplus

I do an export in Excel and draw charts using Epplus:

```
var chart = (ExcelChart)wksh.Drawings.AddChart("Chart", eChartType.Line);
chart.SetSize(500, 300);
chart.SetPosition(5, 800);
chart.Title.Text = "myChart";
chart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(2, 26, rowIndex, 26), ExcelRange.GetAddress(2, 25, rowIndex, 25));
```

And get the chart from left to right by default:

[image]

How do I get the chart from right to left??

[image]

For example, in excel in properties there is a parameter "categories in reverse order":

**how it is done in the Epplus?.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem in which I wanted to flip my y axis, which I fixed with

```
chart.YAxis.Orientation = eAxisOrientation.MaxMin;
```

If you wanted to do x then the same thing (but with x) should work

```
chart.XAxis.Orientation = eAxisOrientation.MaxMin;
```

You may also want to set

```
chart.XAxis.MinValue 
chart.XAxis.MaxValue 
chart.XAxis.Crosses
```

If your formatting looks wonky

Comment: In addition I had to change chart.YAxis.LabelPosition, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637322/829755